# Sub and Function Work Independently but not together

Tags: excel, vba, web-scraping, xmlhttprequest

This question is part of a small series I have posted to try and webscrape `brief profiles` of https://echa.europa.eu/information-on-chemicals

The code uses the Public function `GetUrl`() to retrieve the url of the desired brief profile. This is then used but the SubRoutine GetContents() to scrape the desired data for physical and chemical properties.

Puzzulingly I get a runtime error 91. This is strange because both GetContents() and GetUrl() Work when independent of one another.

Is someone wouldn't mind taking a look that would be great.

```
        Sub GetContents()

Dim xmlReq As New MSXML2.XMLHTTP60
Dim HTMLDoc As New MSHTML.HTMLDocument
            
Dim SubSectList As MSHTML.IHTMLElement
Dim SubSects As MSHTML.IHTMLElementCollection
Dim SubSect As MSHTML.IHTMLElement
                    
Url = GetUrl()
                    
xmlReq.Open "Get", Url, False
xmlReq.send
            
           
If xmlReq.Status <> 200 Then
            
MsgBox "Problem" & vbNewLine & xmlReq.Status & " - " & xmlReq.statusText
Exit Sub

End If
            
HTMLDoc.body.innerHTML = xmlReq.responseText
            
Set SubSectList = HTMLDoc.getElementsByClassName("col-xs-12 col-lg-10 MainContent")(1)
            
Set SubSects = SubSectList.getElementsByTagName("dt")
              
For Each SubSect In SubSects
Debug.Print SubSect.innerText & " : "; SubSect.NextSibling.innerText
Next SubSect

End Sub


Public Function GetUrl() As String
        Const Url = "https://echa.europa.eu/search-for-chemicals?p_auth=5ayUnMyz&p_p_id=disssimplesearch_WAR_disssearchportlet&p_p_lifecycle=1&p_p_state=normal&p_p_col_id=_118_INSTANCE_UFgbrDo05Elj__column-1&p_p_col_count=1&_disssimplesearch_WAR_disssearchportlet_javax.portlet.action=doSearchAction&_disssimplesearch_WAR_disssearchportlet_backURL=https%3A%2F%2Fecha.europa.eu%2Finformation-on-chemicals%3Fp_p_id%3Ddisssimplesearchhomepage_WAR_disssearchportlet%26p_p_lifecycle%3D0%26p_p_state%3Dnormal%26p_p_mode%3Dview%26p_p_col_id%3D_118_INSTANCE_UFgbrDo05Elj__column-1%26p_p_col_count%3D1%26_disssimplesearchhomepage_WAR_disssearchportlet_sessionCriteriaId%3D"
        Dim oHttp As Object, oHtml As HTMLDocument, MyDict As Object, I&, R&
        Dim DictKey As Variant, payload$, searchKeyword$, Ws As Worksheet
        
        Set oHtml = New HTMLDocument
        Set oHttp = CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")
        Set MyDict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
        Set Ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
    
'Keyword can Be any chemical usually set to a cell value i.e. Range("a1").Value
        searchKeyword = "Acetone" '
        
        MyDict("_disssimplesearchhomepage_WAR_disssearchportlet_formDate") = "1621017052777" 'timestamp
        MyDict("_disssimplesearch_WAR_disssearchportlet_searchOccurred") = "true"
        MyDict("_disssimplesearch_WAR_disssearchportlet_sskeywordKey") = searchKeyword
        MyDict("_disssimplesearchhomepage_WAR_disssearchportlet_disclaimer") = "true"
        MyDict("_disssimplesearchhomepage_WAR_disssearchportlet_disclaimerCheckbox") = "on"
    
        payload = ""
        For Each DictKey In MyDict
            payload = IIf(Len(DictKey) = 0, WorksheetFunction.EncodeURL(DictKey) & "=" & WorksheetFunction.EncodeURL(MyDict(DictKey)), _
            payload & "&" & WorksheetFunction.EncodeURL(DictKey) & "=" & WorksheetFunction.EncodeURL(MyDict(DictKey)))
        Next DictKey
        
        With oHttp
            .Open "POST", Url, False
            .setRequestHeader "User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/84.0.4147.135 Safari/537.36"
            .setRequestHeader "Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
            .send (payload)
            oHtml.body.innerHTML = .responseText
        End With
        
        Debug.Print oHtml.querySelector("table.table > tbody > tr > td > a.substanceNameLink").getAttribute("href")
        GetUrl = oHtml.querySelector("table.table > tbody > tr > td > a.substanceNameLink").getAttribute("href")
    
    End Function
```

References:

[image]

Update: What's particularly strange is that the following code works when given an exact url in the code:

```
Sub GetContents()

Dim xmlReq As New MSXML2.XMLHTTP60
Dim HTMLDoc As New MSHTML.HTMLDocument
            
Dim SubSectList As MSHTML.IHTMLElement
Dim SubSects As MSHTML.IHTMLElementCollection
Dim SubSect As MSHTML.IHTMLElement
                    
xmlReq.Open "Get", "https://echa.europa.eu/brief-profile/-/briefprofile/100.028.723", False
xmlReq.send
            
            
If xmlReq.Status <> 200 Then
            
MsgBox "Problem" & vbNewLine & xmlReq.Status & " - " & xmlReq.statusText
Exit Sub

End If
            
HTMLDoc.body.innerHTML = xmlReq.responseText
            
Set SubSectList = HTMLDoc.getElementsByClassName("col-xs-12 col-lg-10 MainContent")(1)
            
Set SubSects = SubSectList.getElementsByTagName("dt")

            
For Each SubSect In SubSects
Debug.Print SubSect.innerText & " : "; SubSect.NextSibling.innerText
Next SubSect

End Sub
```

However Replacing

```
xmlReq.Open "Get", "https://echa.europa.eu/brief-profile/-/briefprofile/100.028.723", False
xmlReq.send
```

with

```
Url = GetUrl()
xmlReq.Open "Get", url, False
    xmlReq.send
```

where GetUrl() refers to the working Public funtion as above

causes the code to break.. with `Set SubSects = SubSectList.getElementsByTagName("dt")` as the problematic line when debugging.

Update Screenshot of result when code provided in answer is run:
[image]

Comment: "a runtime error 91"  - exactly where does this occur?

Comment: Debugging highlights `Set SubSects = SubSectList.getElementsByTagName("dt")` as the problematic line

Comment: I doubt this is the problem but `payload = IIf(Len(DictKey) = 0` should probably be `payload = IIf(Len(payload) = 0`

Comment: Your trials point to a data type error in your function GetURL(). perhaps it returns a variant where it should return a string - something like that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are extracting the wrong url, and there are no dt elements in the html of that URI. Change the css selector and simplify as follows:

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub GetContents()
    Dim XMLReq As New MSXML2.XMLHTTP60
    Dim HTMLDoc As New MSHTML.HTMLDocument
        
    XMLReq.Open "Get", GetUrl, False
    XMLReq.send
                  
    HTMLDoc.body.innerHTML = XMLReq.responseText
    
    Dim i As Long
    
    With HTMLDoc.querySelectorAll(".EndpointContent dt")
        For i = 0 To .Length - 1
            Debug.Print .Item(i).innerText & " : " & .Item(i).NextSibling.NextSibling.innerText
        Next
    End With
End Sub

Public Function GetUrl() As String
    Const url = "https://echa.europa.eu/search-for-chemicals?p_auth=5ayUnMyz&p_p_id=disssimplesearch_WAR_disssearchportlet&p_p_lifecycle=1&p_p_state=normal&p_p_col_id=_118_INSTANCE_UFgbrDo05Elj__column-1&p_p_col_count=1&_disssimplesearch_WAR_disssearchportlet_javax.portlet.action=doSearchAction&_disssimplesearch_WAR_disssearchportlet_backURL=https%3A%2F%2Fecha.europa.eu%2Finformation-on-chemicals%3Fp_p_id%3Ddisssimplesearchhomepage_WAR_disssearchportlet%26p_p_lifecycle%3D0%26p_p_state%3Dnormal%26p_p_mode%3Dview%26p_p_col_id%3D_118_INSTANCE_UFgbrDo05Elj__column-1%26p_p_col_count%3D1%26_disssimplesearchhomepage_WAR_disssearchportlet_sessionCriteriaId%3D"
    Dim oHttp As Object, oHtml As HTMLDocument, MyDict As Object, i&, R&
    Dim DictKey As Variant, payload$, searchKeyword$, Ws As Worksheet
        
    Set oHtml = New HTMLDocument
    Set oHttp = CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")
    Set MyDict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    Set Ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
    
    'Keyword can Be any chemical usually set to a cell value i.e. Range("a1").Value
    searchKeyword = "Acetone"                    '
        
    MyDict("_disssimplesearchhomepage_WAR_disssearchportlet_formDate") = "1621017052777" 'timestamp
    MyDict("_disssimplesearch_WAR_disssearchportlet_searchOccurred") = "true"
    MyDict("_disssimplesearch_WAR_disssearchportlet_sskeywordKey") = searchKeyword
    MyDict("_disssimplesearchhomepage_WAR_disssearchportlet_disclaimer") = "true"
    MyDict("_disssimplesearchhomepage_WAR_disssearchportlet_disclaimerCheckbox") = "on"
    
    payload = ""
        
    For Each DictKey In MyDict
        payload = IIf(Len(DictKey) = 0, WorksheetFunction.EncodeURL(DictKey) & "=" & WorksheetFunction.EncodeURL(MyDict(DictKey)), _
                      payload & "&" & WorksheetFunction.EncodeURL(DictKey) & "=" & WorksheetFunction.EncodeURL(MyDict(DictKey)))
    Next DictKey
        
    With oHttp
        .Open "POST", url, False
        .setRequestHeader "User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/84.0.4147.135 Safari/537.36"
        .setRequestHeader "Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
        .send (payload)
        oHtml.body.innerHTML = .responseText
    End With
        
    Debug.Print oHtml.querySelector(".briefProfileLink").getAttribute("href")
    GetUrl = oHtml.querySelector(".briefProfileLink").getAttribute("href")
    
End Function
```

Comment: My code, as is written, runs without error for me. You pulled the wrong url because you used the wrong css selector.

Comment: Hm I dont understand it then, copying your answer into a new module still causes this error. Maybe my computer? Thank you for your help!

Comment: What is the error message and on which line?

Comment: Ive replaced the update with a screenshot. The url is printed and then it starts printing the properties as desired but after `C Odour: C Substance Type` I get `Run-time error '91': Object Variable or with block variable not set`. With the debig showing the highlighted line as the problem.

Comment: I cannot reproduce this.

Comment: Okay the last thing I can think of as a test is If I can share the document with you. I have uploaded the problematic file here: https://1drv.ms/u/s!AsrLaUgt0KCLhXtP-jYDd4Z0ujKQ?e=IuBjKC If you wouldn't mind running the code in the Get_Data Module and just letting me know how it works out then we know its something outside of VBA. Hope thats okay!

Comment: Just tested it out on another PC and it works fine. Weird

Comment: If you change the css selector in my previous answer you will have a more re-usable integration.

Comment: Hi again I did that and It works better so thank you! Also whats the purpose of the long Url? Why not just https://echa.europa.eu/search-for-chemicals?

Comment: I used the url provided in SIM's answer. It looks like a querystring which usually determines what comes back in the request. More typically associated with GET request. If a shorter url returns the desired results, use that.